# How to add different level bars in one plot of JFreeChart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I created JFreeChart, using CandleSeries and OHLCSeries data and print Candles correctly.

I want add Volume Bars with transparency color, like as in example picture below.

Have You got any sample codes with printing Candles and Bars below(as in example picture)?

Example picture:
[image: Exmaple]

Comment: Have you looked at the financial charts tab of the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html)?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland You'are right, I will check ;) Have You any basic sample?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland I checked JfreeChart site and sample there but there is developer guide which needs payments

Comment: Ask your manager or search for the closest match.